# Neo4J using long as Entity ID doesn't appear to work

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I am embarking on my first project using Neo4J as my primary data-store.
We are using Snowflake.Net for our ID generation system.

This all worked well in the beginning as we were saving the ID's as strings to overcome limitations of longs in javascript. this how ever proved to be a poor design decision as it made things like paging very difficult.

We have subsequently re-factored so that we are using a long (64bit int) as an Id
Which Generates an ID like this: 5836423911667012000
However now we are not able to match using ID's (Please see attached Images)
http://i28.photobucket.com/albums/c222/primalfear83/c1_zpsa2893e35.png
http://i28.photobucket.com/albums/c222/primalfear83/c2_zps6b335e02.png

Our Id field does work if we use a 32bit int, but not with any 64bit int values.
So we can look up on an ID 57073.

Any insight as to the cause behind this, or possibly solutions to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think i have found the source of the problem.. having dug a bit deeper, it appears to be an issue with out its being displayed, I have inspected the web traffic with fiddler and in the RAW the Id is being set as 436565277858205696 but when i view the Json submission it shows as: 4.365652778582057E+17 When looking at the node is NEO4J it show the node having an Id of 436565277858205700 the interesting bit comes in when i write the query: if i try using 436565277858205700 i get no results, but i do get a hit using 436565277858205696.

Comment: The issue appears to be in the Neo4J Web administration UI, where on the output on the UI is not a true indication of what is happening in the database. I have done a few more tests and all my statements are now working fine, as long as i don't try and use the values displayed in the web admin... makes testing painful, but I'll survive :p

True ID: 436565277858205696 | Web Admin: 436565277858205700
True ID: 436570021204987904 | Web Admin: 436570021204987900

Seams to be rounding the last few digits :@

Comment: You should report this at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be in the Neo4J Web administration UI, where on the output on the UI is not a true indication of what is happening in the database.

I have done a few more tests and all my statements are now working fine, as long as i don't try and use the values displayed in the web admin... 
True ID: 436565277858205696 | Web Admin: 436565277858205700
True ID: 436570021204987904 | Web Admin: 436570021204987900

Comment: Issue has been added:
I have also included more of my findings, and also the root cause.
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2028